# Не корректно прописываются пути для шрифтов

Tags: webpack4

1 Неправильно переносятся шрифты

2 Неправильно прописываются пути к шрифтам в Css

```
    // Config
                {
                    test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff(2)?)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                    use: [{
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'fonts/'
                        }
                    }]
            },

    // Sass
    @font-face
        font-family: 'Open Sans'
        font-style: normal
        font-weight: 300
        src: url('../fonts/opensans/OpenSansLight/OpenSansLight.woff') format('woff')

// BUILD
dist/fonts/src/fonts/opensans/OpenSansLight/OpenSansLight.woff  

// Compiled Css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url(/fonts/src/fonts/opensans/OpenSansLight/OpenSansLight.woff) format("woff"); }
```

this link template
https://dropmefiles.com/BZ2sr

Comment: А как заголовок (почему то пока не переведённый) отражает ваш вопрос? В первой версии было как-то понятно, сейчас не совсем.

Comment: Отредактировал заголовок